# Spring data jpa supports PagingandSorting on mysql views?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a view which combines 8 tables, total records will be more than 1 million. When I try to fetch, It creates heap space issue. I thought of calling records using paging and sorting mechanism. Is there a way to achieve this.

Can I use procedure instead of views. Does spring data jpa supports pagination for procedure

Answer (score 0):

you can just add pageable param in your repository function. Then the framework will do all the left.
You should check the [ref](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.9.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories)

Comment: I am getting following error  org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.InvalidJpaQueryMethodException: Cannot use native queries with dynamic sorting and/or pagination in method public abstract

Comment: No, you should not use `nativeQuery` with paging in param. You should use `Query`, it is like HQL of hibernate.